# Drawing distance lines between two points

Tags: qgis, distance

I want to be able to generate a distance line between two points on the map, which also has the distance as a label (similar to the second image seen on Google maps or in the first image from the red point to Aberdeen).I have used the `measure line tool` and it has provided myself with a distance, however I am yet to figure out how to produce a line with the classified distance labeled on it. does anyone know how to solve this issue. I am using QGIS versions 3.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: I posted that as well, but I have been put on hold, even though I have made the amendments required. I have a deadline due today and needed to know how to do this

Comment: Do not post the same question many times. Your previous question is now under review to reopen it again. Please wait.

Comment: sorry, I will know that from now on. I am new to this sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can draw a vector line from one point to the other. In the attribute table you can calculate the length with the `$length` and then label it with this attribute.

In the attribute table, use the field calculator to add a new column (figure 1) then open the properties to label it (figure 2)

[image: Length calculation]

[image: Label]